# DataGridView cells type

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have datagridview with checkbox column, but I want, that some of the columns cells are textbox cells. 
Is it possible to have multiple cells types in one column? If yes, then how?

Comment: you want to see for ex: textbox and label in one column right ?

Comment: @ADT Yes, that is correct, but I want to see in one column Checkbox and textbox

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There're two ways to do this:

1. Cast a `DataGridViewCell` to a certain cell type that exists. For example, convert a `DataGridViewTextBoxCell` to `DataGridViewComboBoxCell` type.
2. Create a control and add it into the controls collection of `DataGridView`, set its location and size to fit the cell that to be host.

See my sample code below which illustrates the tricks:

```
private void Form5_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   DataTable dt = new DataTable();
   dt.Columns.Add("name");
   for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) { dt.Rows.Add(""); }
   this.dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
   this.dataGridView1.Columns[0].Width = 200;

   // First method : Convert to an existed cell type such ComboBox cell, etc 
   DataGridViewComboBoxCell ComboBoxCell = new DataGridViewComboBoxCell();
   ComboBoxCell.Items.AddRange(new string[] { "aaa","bbb","ccc" });
   this.dataGridView1[0, 0] = ComboBoxCell;
   this.dataGridView1[0, 0].Value = "bbb";

   DataGridViewTextBoxCell TextBoxCell = new DataGridViewTextBoxCell();
   this.dataGridView1[0, 1] = TextBoxCell;
   this.dataGridView1[0, 1].Value = "some text";

   DataGridViewCheckBoxCell CheckBoxCell = new DataGridViewCheckBoxCell();
   CheckBoxCell.Style.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
   this.dataGridView1[0, 2] = CheckBoxCell;
   this.dataGridView1[0, 2].Value = true;

   // Second method : Add control to the host in the cell
   DateTimePicker dtp = new DateTimePicker();
   dtp.Value = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-10);
   //add DateTimePicker into the control collection of the DataGridView
   this.dataGridView1.Controls.Add(dtp);
   //set its location and size to fit the cell
   dtp.Location = this.dataGridView1.GetCellDisplayRectangle(0, 3,true).Location;
   dtp.Size = this.dataGridView1.GetCellDisplayRectangle(0, 3,true).Size;
}
```

Referenced from [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winformsdesigner/thread/63ddb457-f769-44db-87cc-9e88e74929e8/).